# Abrir vista en otra ventana

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un botón donde me re direcciona a una vista que me abre un PDF, pero lo que quiero es que no me cargue la pagina en la que estoy, si no que me devuelva la vista en una pestaña nueva.

```
public ActionResult Print(int? id, string Text, int? Contacto, string ContactoDos)
        {
                    
                    case 2020:
                        //DATOS CLOUD
                        return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("Cloud");
                }


            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                return Json(e.Message);
            }

            return View("Index");
        }
```

Es una función muy larga donde tengo un `switch` para devolver la vista en PDF dependiendo de ciertos casos...

Y en el botón donde tengo para abrir esa vista, es un `functión` donde por medio de `ajax` mando a llamar esa vista

Comment: `target=_blank`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Dale un simple `<a href="<nombre de tu action>"`
2. Utiliza el atributo `"target=_blank"`

### Observaciones generales

Los parámetros opcionales van al final, esto es una buena práctica.

Comment: Y dentro de una función no se podría? Es que es un `button` y no un `a`, y en el botón tengo un onClick donde me manda a una función y por medio de ajax llamo a esa función

Comment: Misma situación. El problema ahora es que con este comentario, la pregunta se transforma en otra.

Comment: @Luis lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Especialmente punto 2. Saludos.

Comment: @Luis Es posible hacerlo por Ajax, pero es que no tiene sentido alguno, es querer que todo sea ultra complejo a posta. Tú quieres mostrar un PDF en una nueva pestaña, la solución es colocar un link y punto

Comment: Es que primero se abre un modal, y en ese modal ya me genera el archivo PDF

Comment: @Luis a la sala de chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol